# Simple limit question involving binomial coefficient $\lim \binom{n}{n-k} (p)^n (1-p)^n$ where $0 \leq p \leq 1$

Tags: limits, binomial-coefficients

The question is pretty simple, how does one compute $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \binom{n}{n-k} (p)^n (1-p)^n$ where $0 \leq p \leq 1$ and $0 \leq n-k \leq n$?

Some checking with wolfram (and the context of the problem that this is involved in) tells me that this should go to zero, but I'm not sure how to show this. I have tried bounding this above by $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} n! (p)^n (1-p)^n$, but I think this diverges to infinity.

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: I think there is a simple way to do this limit using binomial distribution. I would rearrange $\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} \binom{n}{n-k}p^n(1-p)^n = \lim\limits_{n \to \infty} \frac{\binom{n}{k}p^k(1-p)^{n-k}}{p^k(1-p)^{-k}p^{-n}}$ and noticing that the numerator is the sum of $n$ independant Bernoulli of parameter $p$. I hope it helps.

Comment: Ratio test should be easier

Answer (score 1):

$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} n! (p)^n (1-p)^n$ diverges to infinity, as the factorial grows faster than the exponential function (with base $<1$) decreases to zero. But you don't have just the factorial, you have $$\binom{n}{n-k}=\binom{n}{k}=\prod_{j=1}^k\frac{n+1-j}{j}=\mathcal O(n^k)\qquad\text{for }n\to\infty.$$
And you know, that the exponential function (with base $<1$) decreases faster to zero than any polynomial.

If your $k$ is not fixed, i.e. $k=k(n)$, you could use that the binomial coefficient is taking it's maximum in "the middle":
$$\binom{n}{k(n)}\leq\binom{n}{\lfloor n/2\rfloor}=\mathcal O(2^n)\qquad\text{for }n\to\infty.
$$
But the last fact "$=\mathcal O(2^n)$" is a thing of its own and I don't know if it's easy to proof. One way could be to proof $$\forall n\in\mathbb N:\binom{n}{\lfloor n/2\rfloor}\leq 2^n$$ by mathematical induction.